# Unknown rotate/add data integrity check algorithm

Tags: c, checksum, data-integrity

I was looking at some code that loads data into memory, and at the end of the load, it preforms some type of integrity check on the data. The integrity check reads the buffer in chunks of 4 bytes and adds them to an accumulator, rotating right the accumulator by `1` between each addition. If the accumulator ends up 0, data is OK.

I know the last bytes of the buffer are not part of the data itself, which means the last 4 bytes are the "magic number" to rollover the accumulator to 0. I also know that it's using chunks of 4 bytes specifically as that is it's defaulting to 32bit CPUs. Attached is a recreation of the code:

```
#define ROR32(i,c) ((i >> c)|(i << (32 - c)))
void check(uint32_t *buffer, uint32_t size) {
        uint32_t i, ret = 0;
        for (i=0; i < size/4 ; i++) {
                ret = ROR32(ret, 1);
                ret += buffer[i];
        }

        if (ret)
                printf("Data corrupt (%d)\n", ret);
        else
                printf("Data OK.\n");
}
```

I was looking to know if this is a standard integrity algorithm (does it have a name?) and why the bit rotation? I did not find anything similar, as the search keywords "checksum" "integrity" "ror" and "sum" are to vague for any meaningful results.

Thank you.

Comment: Seems to be modified from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_checksum ?

Comment: The bit rotation is *necessary*, a simple addition would not notice swapping two 32-bit values. I do not know if it is your doing but as it is written now, it will consider only every 4th 32-bit unit...

Comment: Antti Haapala, I was thinking of a BSD checksum (it came up in results) but as you stated, it's modified somewhat and I'm trying to see if it's a standard. Thanks for the tip on the bit rotation, makes a lot of sense now. The implementation is my fault (I read it with gaps by mistake). Thanks.